# Create GLSurfaceView from OpenGL ES texture

Tags: android, qt, opengl-es

I need to implement a video call feature in a QT app for Android. I've found that it's a pretty complicated and time consuming task to do using QT, as there are no such modules that allow to do that easily. On the other hand, there are plenty of Android libraries and frameworks, that already do it.
So my choice right now is to integrate an android library into my QT project.

The library uses `GLSurfaceView` to show video call:

```
GLSurfaceView videoView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.glview_call);
```

I know that `GLSurfaceView` must be using OpenGL ES texture under the hood.
I would like to understand how to create `GLSurfaceView` from a raw texture (`glGenTextures`), so that the Android library could render into it, and I'll be controlling on QT side where to place this texture on the screen.

Do you know any ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like `TextureView` with its `setSurfaceTexture(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture)` method is the way to go. `SurfaceTexture` accepts texture id in its constructor. Though it will take some time to check if it really works.